# How to convert 2019-08-15 date format to August 15, 2019 in the command line?

Tags: command-line, date

Given a `bash` variable with the value `2019-08-15`, is there some utility that can convert that date to the format `August 15, 2019`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert Date formate in unix](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/336857/convert-date-formate-in-unix)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On Linux, or any system that uses GNU `date`:

```
$ thedate=2019-08-15
$ date -d "$thedate" +'%B %e, %Y'
August 15, 2019
```

On macOS, OpenBSD and FreeBSD, where GNU `date` is not available by default:

```
$ thedate=2019-08-15
$ date -j -f '%Y-%m-%d' "$thedate" +'%B %e, %Y'
August 15, 2019
```

The `-j` option disables setting the system clock, and the format string used with `-f` describes the input date format (should be a [`strptime(3)`](https://man.openbsd.org/strptime) format string describing the format used by your variable's value). Then follows the value of your variable and the format that you want your output to be in (should be a [`strftime(3)`](https://man.openbsd.org/strftime) format string).

NetBSD users may use something similar to the above but without the `-f input_fmt` option, as their `date` implementation uses [`parsedate(3)`](https://netbsd.gw.com/cgi-bin/man-cgi?parsedate+3+NetBSD-current).  Note also the `-d` option to specify the input date string:

```
$ thedate=2019-08-15
$ date -j -d "$thedate" +'%B %e, %Y'
August 15, 2019
```

See also the manual for `date` on your system.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that you have access to GNU `date`, something along

```
$ date --date="2019-08-15" "+%B %d, %Y"
August 15, 2019
```

Check the manpage of *date* (`man date`).